# 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that is a service that lists wifi access points and their details. When I first run rosrun there's no errors. Then I make a service request and it says Error processing request: 'type' object is not subscriptable. I'm sure it's a basic Python error but I can't figure out what it is. Thanks!

The relevant code:

```
    ssid_list.append(ssid)
    strength_list.append(strength)
    secured_list.append(secured)

  return WifiListResponse[String(ssid_list), UInt8(strength_list), Bool(secured_list)]
```

my .srv file:

```
int8 request
---
string[] ssid_list
uint8[] strength_list
bool[] secured_list
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39550/%27type%27-object-is-not-subscriptable/) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-23**:
Unfortunately, I think the code you pasted is not enough to infer what's going wrong. Please paste the complete relevant code not just snippets that don't contain any context. Also, please copy-paste the complete backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code is not valid Python.

Try something like

```
WifiListResponse(ssid_list, strength_list, secured_list)
```

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2